# FileNotFoundException when loading a file

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm very new with Solr (installed it yesterday...) and I already have the first problem.

I have my dir `Solr-Indexing` where I copied the `post.jar` and where I have my core dir `Collection1`. In `Collection1` I have the `conf` dir with the `schema.xml`, `solrconfig.xml` and some pdf documents (which I want to import/index).

I start my Solr instance with `java -Dsolr.solr.home="D:/download/Solr-Test/Solr-Indexing" -jar start.jar`(I see no problems in the log) and then I try to load a pdf in my collection with the command `java -Dtype=application/pdf -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update/extract -jar post.jar collection1/Lucene.pdf`.

The output is the following:

```
D:\download\Solr-Test\Solr-Indexing>java -Dtype=application/pdf -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update/extract -jar post.jar collection1/Lucene.pdf
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update/extract using content-type application/pdf..
POSTing file Lucene.pdf
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 Not Found
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update/extract
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update/extract..
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #404 Not Found for url http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update/extract?commit=true
Time spent: 0:00:00.015
```

Where is the problem? Do I miss something?

What I can see ist that the URL in browser is `http://localhost:8983/solr/#/Collection1` with a `#` and what I use is without `#`. Could this be a problem? I tried to add the `#` in my command too, but then I get the message:

```
D:\download\Solr-Test\Solr-Indexing>java -Dtype=application/pdf -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/update/extract -jar post.jar collection1/Lucene.pdf
SimplePostTool version 1.5
Posting files to base url http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/update/extract using content-type application/pdf..
POSTing file Lucene.pdf
SimplePostTool: WARNING: Solr returned an error #405 HTTP method POST is not supported by this URL
SimplePostTool: WARNING: IOException while reading response: java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 405 for URL: http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/update/extract
1 files indexed.
COMMITting Solr index changes to http://localhost:8983/solr/#/collection1/update/extract..
Time spent: 0:00:00.031
```

Here are my schema.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<schema name="simple" version="1.1">
  <types>
    <fieldtype name="string" class="solr.StrField"/>
    <fieldtype name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField"/>
    <fieldtype name='text' class='solr.TextField'>
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class='solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory' />
            <filter class='solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory' />
        </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>
  </types>

  <fields>
    <field name="id" type="long" required="true" />
    <field name='fullText' type='text' multiValued='true' />
    <dynamicField name="*" type="string" multiValued="true" indexed="true" stored="true" />
    <copyField source="*" dest="fulltext" />
  </fields>

  <uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
  <defaultSearchField>fullText</defaultSearchField>
  <solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR" />
</schema>
```

and solrconfig.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config>
  <luceneMatchVersion>LUCENE_45</luceneMatchVersion>
  <directoryFactory name='DirectoryFactory' class='solr.MMapDirectoryFactory' />

  <lib dir='${solr.core.instanceDir}\lib' />

  <requestHandler name='standard' class='solr.StandardRequestHandler' default='true' />
  <requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler" />
  <requestHandler name='/update' class='solr.UpdateRequestHandler' />
  <requestHandler name='/update/extract' class='solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler'>
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="uprefix">s_meta_</str>
    <str name="fmap.content">t_content</str>
    <str name="fmap.dcterms:created">d_created</str>
  </lst>
  </requestHandler>
  <requestHandler name='/admin/' class='org.apache.solr.handler.admin.AdminHandlers' />
  <admin>
    <defaultQuery>*:*</defaultQuery>
  </admin>

</config>
```

As you can see, I'm on a windows(7) machine.

Comment: have you tried specifying the full path to the pdf file using forward or backward slashes?

Comment: Yes, I tried all the possible combinations...

Comment: well one option, if you are not afraid of installing additional software, is to try posting from cygwin. In that case you can use forward slashes and relative paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a file path error. Try `collection1\conf\Lucene.pdf`. You're using a windows machine, use `\`.

What the error is telling you is that it can't find the pdf file you specified. So the last part of the command, "collection1\Lucene.pdf" should be the culprit. You said you put the pdf files to be indexed in collection1\conf. So you should try this:

`java -Dtype=application/pdf -Durl=http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/update/extract -jar post.jar collection1\conf\Lucene.pdf`

If it still doesn't work, try giving the full path to the pdf you're trying to index.

Word of advice: When learning Solr, don't begin by messing with file structure.

Comment: Also, the "#" in the URL is irrelevant.

Comment: Hi KrackJack, with or without "#" should be relevant, see that the error message is different. Anyway, I tried with the full path in both cases, but the problem remains the same and the error messages too...

Comment: Use a backslash instead of a forward slash, mate. You're on windows. XD

Comment: If you mean to use the backslash in the URL, this is the result: `SimplePostTool: FATAL: System Property 'url' is not a valid URL: http\\localhost:8983\solr\cell\update\extract`. If you mean in the path for the file, I already tried to have the pdf in the same location as the jar, so that I can write just the file name, but nothing changes...